Why did Steve request Frank’s confirmation on whether Susie remained standing?
Steve forcefully broke up with J.J.'s sister, Susie, after bidding her a final
goodbye with a kiss. He then departed with Frank, pausing their journey at a
certain location:

Steve: Look back and see if she's still standing there.
Frank: She's still standing there.

Then scene then slowly shifts to the next.
Why did Steve request Frank’s confirmation on whether Susie remained standing?

He didn't want her to see him looking back

@Valorum Can you elaborate bit more and post it as answer?
